# Can't access Enum<?>.valueOf(String) method for generic type (or how to get .class of generic argument)?

Tags: java, generics

How can I access static method of the enum if given enum is a parameter of generic class?

Consider following example

```
public class EnumListBox<T extends Enum<T>> extends ListBox implements LeafValueEditor<T>
{
    @Override
    public void setValue(T value)
    {
        // something..
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue()
    {
        int ndx = getSelectedIndex();
        String val = getValue(ndx);
        return T.valueOf(val);
    }
}
```

For some reason `Enum<?>.valueOf(String)` is not available to me. Another version of this method has two parameters and wants `Class<Enum<?>>` which I can't instantiate as `T.class`.

How would you fix this? Basically I want to have universal ListBox wrapper for any enum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest fix is to pass an instance of the enum *class* in the constructor for `EnumListBox`.

```
public class EnumListBox<T extends Enum<?>> extends ListBox implements LeafValueEditor<T>
{
    private final Class<T> mClazz;

    public EnumListBox(Class<T> clazz) {
        mClazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue()
    {
        int ndx = getSelectedIndex();
        String val = getValue(ndx);
        return Enum.valueOf(mClazz, val);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ruslan What's the problem with this solution?

Comment: @ruslan - What do you mean that it's not universal? It's basically the same trick that [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) uses.

Comment: @natix I think he wants to use wrapper class without any parameterized constructors.

Comment: @CengizCan - He may want that, but because of type erasure, it's not going to happen.

Comment: One thing I am not sure is that: what if T (an enum) defined a static method named valueOf(Class<?>, name), will there be any differences between Enum.valueOf(*,*) and T.valueOf(*,*)? Thanks.

Comment: @michael - static methods are accessed based on the qualifier used. Thus, `Enum.valueOf(,)` would access the method defined in class `Enum` and `T.valueOf(,)` would access the method defined in class `T`. As a matter of style, I would strongly recommend against that kind of name reuse.

Comment: @TedHopp Yes, usually,we prefer the Enum.valueOf; however, for the legacy code, the T.valueOf() sometimes may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use of reflection tends to be a bad idea. Unfortunately there is no non-reflection meta enum type in Java. In this case we just need the list of actual values.

```
public class EnumListBox<T extends Enum<T>> extends ListBox implements LeafValueEditor<T> {
    private final List<T> values;

    public EnumListBox(T[] values) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values.clone()));
    }

    @Override public void setValue(T value) {
        // something..
    }

    @Override public T getValue() {
        int index = getSelectedIndex();
        return values.get(index);
    }
}
```

Construct as `new EnumListBox<>(MyEnum.values())`. You don't really have to tie the class to enums.

Comment: Good point. I was forced to use ListBox because I need its values to be localized therefore they have to be defined in uiBinder template. Maybe there is better way but I don't know it yet. I'm going to post specific question about it later.